# BeautifulSoup: Return None if HTML element not found

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to search for several elements in a web page.

I'm saving the elements I find, but because there is a chance that my script will look for an element and it doesn't exist for the particular page it's parsing, I have try/except statements for every element:

```python
# go through a bunch of webpages
for soup in soups:
    try: # look for HTML element
         data['val1'].append(soup.find('div', class_="something").text)
    except: # add NA if nothing found
        data['val1'].append("N/A")
    try:
        data['val2'].append(soup.find('span', class_="something else").text)
    except:
        data['val2'].append("N/A")

    # and more and more try/excepts for more elements of interest
```

Is there a cleaner or better way to write something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation about the [find method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find). It will return None if can’t find anything. So the Exception occurs when you call the property 'text' of None.

Maybe you should take a look at the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python) in Python to see how you can do it.

```
result = soup.find('div', class_="something")
data['val1'].append(result.text if result else "N/A")
```

Also as Dan-Dev pointed out [catching an exception is expensive](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions):

> A try/except block is extremely efficient if no exceptions are raised. Actually catching an exception is expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Try except is expensive. I'd use an if else statement.

```
v = soup.find('div', class_="something")
if v:
    data['val1'].append(v.text)
else:
    data['val1'].append("N/A")
```

Comment: I tried this initially but I moved to try/excepts because occasional errors broke the if/else strategy.

Answer (score 2):

This achieves what you want and also reduces code repetition a bit more by wrapping things in a for loop:

```python
info= [("val1", "div", "something"),
       ("val2", "span", "something else")]

# go through a bunch of webpages
for soup in soups:
    for (val, element, class1) in info:
        query = soup.find(element, class_=class1)
        data[val].append(query.text if query else "N/A")
```

Comment: Yeah a for loop would be great for my example, but I realized the way I search for elements in my actual script changes often, making the for loop impractical.