# How to prevent error when webscraping with python and value is not there?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Right now I'm trying to go through a real estate website and scrape data on properties. I've got a code that goes through the list of properties gets data, and then goes to the page for each property and gets more detailed data. It works but the problem is that if any field is missing I get an error that causes an exception and makes it skip to the next property. Instead I'd like to have it just put a null for any missing data I'm new to Python and webscraping so there might be more insights on how to clean my code up so feel free to comment on that as well but mostly I'm just trying to get it to put nulls where it finds missing data.  Here's the code where prop_list is the html code for

```
for item in prop_list:
    try:
        d ={}
        d["address"] = item.find("span", {"itemprop":"streetAddress"}).text
        d["city"] = item.find("span", {"itemprop":"addressLocality"}).text
        d["state"] = item.find("span", {"itemprop":"addressRegion"}).text
        d["zip_code"] = item.find("span", {"itemprop":"postalCode"}).text
        d["price"] = item.find("span", {"class":"data-price"}).text
        d["lot_sqft"] = item.find("li", {"data-label":"property-meta-lotsize"}).find("span", {"class":"data-value"}).text           
        link = item.find("a").get("href")
        url = "https://www.realtor.com" + link
        d["url"] = url
        d["longitude"] = item.find("meta",{"itemprop":"longitude"}).get("content")
        d["latitude"] = item.find("meta",{"itemprop":"latitude"}).get("content")
        desc_link = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        b = desc_link.content
        temp = BeautifulSoup(b,"html.parser")
        d["description"] = temp.find("p", {"class": "word-wrap-break"})
        d["year_built"] = temp.find("li", {"data-label": "property-year"}).find("div", {"class":"key-fact-data ellipsis"}).text

        l.append(d)

    except:
        print("exception occurred")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this gives you some ideas?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661994/beautifulsoup-return-none-if-html-element-not-found

You could wrap a try/except around each dictionary key assignment, but that doesn't feel... clean.

Comment: Can you provide some example urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're a beginner, I'd elaborate your code in this way. Just use a if-else statement like this:

```
if item.find("span", {"itemprop" : "streetAddress"}):
    d["address"] = item.find("span", {"itemprop":"streetAddress"}).text
else:
    d["address"] = "" # or None
```

Now doing like this for each element would be hectic, so in the Pythonic way:

```
d["address"] = item.find("span", {"itemprop":"streetAddress"}).text if item.find("span", {"itemprop":"streetAddress"}) else ""
```

This would get you exactly what you need.

Comment: Awesome! I just ran it an it seems to be doing exactly what you said. Thank for the help

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that if you don't find a specific element then trying to get `elem.text` from it generates exception. If that is the case, then you can do this:

```
d["address"] = item.find("span", {"itemprop":"streetAddress"}).text if item.find("span", {"itemprop":"streetAddress"}) else "-"
```

or another way to avoid exception, but this way you cannot set default value like "-":

```
d["address"] = item.find("span", {"itemprop":"streetAddress"}) and item.find("span", {"itemprop":"streetAddress"}).text
```