# How to add a condition to an Error:NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

*Help*

I've been trying to skip an error if theres no "text", but any try I did, did not work. So I'm bit worry, I'm new in this world of code, but this code behind works when theres always "text" to extract.

Someone can tell me where to put the condition?
:/

````
import  requests
import pandas as pd

baseUrl = "https://www.sodimac.cl"

headers = {
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}

productlinks =[]

for x in range(1,7):
    r = requests.get(f"https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-cl/category/scat922339/Ceramicas?currentpage={x}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='jsx-3663142191 search-results-products-container')
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', id="title-pdp-link", href=True):
            productlinks.append(baseUrl + link['href'])

Ceramicaslist = []
for  link in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    name = soup.find('div', class_='jsx-4129468047 product-brand').text.strip()
    descripcion = soup.find('h1', class_='jsx-4129468047 product-title').text.strip()
    modelo = soup.find('div', class_='jsx-4129468047 product-model').text.strip()
    SKU = soup.find('div', class_='jsx-4129468047 product-cod').text.strip()
    precio = soup.find('span', class_='jsx-3655512908').text.strip()

    Ceramicas = {
        'name': name,
        'descripcion': descripcion,
        'modelo': modelo,
        'SKU': SKU,
        'precio': precio
}

Ceramicaslist.append(Ceramicas)
print('Saving: ', Ceramicas['name'], Ceramicas['descripcion'], Ceramicas['modelo'],Ceramicas['SKU'], Ceramicas['precio'])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(Ceramicaslist)
print(df)
df.to_csv('CeramicasSodimac.csv')**strong text**```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soup.find() returns None if there is no match so you will need to account for that.  there are a number of ways to do that with if and try blocks. I would probably do:

```
def safe_text(el): return el.text.strip() if el else "n/a"
```

Then you can:

```
name = safe_text(soup.find('div', class_='jsx-4129468047 product-brand'))
```

Comment: if soup.find("div", class_="product-model"):
        modelo = soup.find("div", class_="product-model").text.strip()
    else:
        modelo = ""  #or none .    I finally did this, saw in another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54799306/how-to-prevent-error-when-webscraping-with-python-and-value-is-not-there    THANKS <3

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `jsx-XXXX` part from your `class_=` parameters:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseUrl = "https://www.sodimac.cl"

headers = {
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
}

productlinks = []

for x in range(1, 7):
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-cl/category/scat922339/Ceramicas?currentpage={x}"
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    productlist = soup.find_all(
        "div", class_="search-results-products-container"
    )
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all("a", id="title-pdp-link", href=True):
            productlinks.append(baseUrl + link["href"])

Ceramicaslist = []
for link in productlinks:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    name = soup.find("div", class_="product-brand").text.strip()
    descripcion = soup.find("h1", class_="product-title").text.strip()
    modelo = soup.find("div", class_="product-model").text.strip()
    SKU = soup.find("div", class_="product-cod").text.strip()
    precio = soup.find("div", class_="price").span.text.strip()

    Ceramicas = {
        "name": name,
        "descripcion": descripcion,
        "modelo": modelo,
        "SKU": SKU,
        "precio": precio,
    }

    Ceramicaslist.append(Ceramicas)
    print(
        "Saving: ",
        Ceramicas["name"],
        Ceramicas["descripcion"],
        Ceramicas["modelo"],
        Ceramicas["SKU"],
        Ceramicas["precio"],
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(Ceramicaslist)
print(df)
df.to_csv('CeramicasSodimac.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
Saving:  Cordillera Cerámica café 45x45 cm 2,08 m2 Modelo Lato Código 2184680 $5.990
Saving:  Cordillera Cerámica beige 45,3x45,3 2,05 m2 Modelo Grava Código 4213564 $6.990
Saving:  Holztek Cerámica Muro blanco 20x30 cm 1,5 m2 Modelo Blanco Código 1791893 $4.990
Saving:  Scop Cerámica café 33x33 cm 1,96 m2 Modelo Canelo Código 4213483 $4.290
Saving:  Scop Cerámica gris 33x33 cm 1,96 m2 Modelo Granito Código 421367X $4.590
Saving:  Cordillera Cerámica 45x45 cm adoquín gris 2,08 m2 Modelo Adoquín Código 6401317 $6.490
Saving:  Cordillera Ceramica miel 60x60 cm 1,44 m2 Modelo Legno Código 3099318 $8.890
Saving:  Cordillera Cerámica multicolor 45x45 cm 2,08 m2 Modelo Madera Murcia Código 309930X $7.290
Saving:  Cordillera Cerámica 45x45 cm adoquín beige 2,08 m2 Modelo Adoquín Código 6401309 $7.990
Saving:  Bs Cerámica Muro gris 20x30 cm 1,5 m2 Modelo Carla Código 1004395 $7.990
Saving:  Holztek Cerámica café 53x53 cm 2,29 m2 Modelo Laminato Código 2669188 $8.790
Saving:  Scop Cerámica café 45,3x45,3 cm 2,05 m2 Modelo Canelo Código 4213505 $5.690
Saving:  Cordillera Cerámica café 45,3x45,3 cm 2,05 m2 Modelo Nogal Código 4213513 $6.990
Saving:  Cordillera Cerámica multicolor 45x45 cm 2,08 m2 Modelo Limari Código 3099237 $5.990
Saving:  Holztek Cerámica café 45x45 cm 2 m2 Modelo HD Rustico Código 2742322 $6.490
Saving:  Cordillera Cerámica 34x34 parma gray 1,66 m2 Modelo PARMA Código 6448267 $7.490
Saving:  Bs Fachaleta Muro 30x60 grafito 1,53 m2 Modelo CERLAJ36000 Código 3664864 $12.990


...and so on.
```

Comment: Got an error in `precio = soup.find('div', class_="price").span.text.strip()`
AtributeError: 'NoneType' object  has no attribute 'span'

But worked in the first data, for that reason if you know a simple way of skip the error hehe

But thanks, sweat change got almost all (im trying hard on this, but first time asked 4help in here)

*Learning*

Comment: The script is doing fine. I just tested it @Esteban García.

Comment: if soup.find("div", class_="product-model"):
        modelo = soup.find("div", class_="product-model").text.strip()
    else:
        modelo = ""  #or none

solved!  thanks <3