# Writing сsv outout in order

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

After scraping infos from site I get table rows like that

```
1 ASICS MEN'S GEL NIMBUS 21 RUNNING Training sport    
2
3 ALL/STAR Chuck Taylor Uomo Donna Unisex Maglia Scarpe         
4
5 Men's adidas UltraBOOST 20 Running Shoes EF1043,US,$115.00,167,
6
7 Skechers Sport Black shoes Men Memory Foam Walk Mesh Running sports Casual Shoes
```

See also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNxqL.png).

The question is whay table row is missing 2,4,6,8 lines.

```
# TODO
# 1. Make a request to the ebay.com and get a page
# 2. Collect data from each detail page
# 3. Collect all links to detail pages of each product
# 4. Write scraped data to a csv file

import csv

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_data(url):
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}) #this was missing
    
    if not response.ok:
        print('Server Responded: {}'.format(response.status_code))
        soup = None
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):
    # title
    # price
    # items sold
    try:
        title = soup.find('h1', id='itemTitle').text.strip()
    except:
        title = ''
        
    try:
        p = soup.find('span', id='prcIsum').text.strip()
        currency, price = p.split(' ')
    except:
        currency = ''
        price = ''
    
    try:
        sold = soup.find('span', class_='vi-qtyS-hot-red').a.text.strip().split(' ')[0]
    except:
        sold = ''
    
    data = {
        'title' : title,
        'currency' : currency,
        'price' : price,
        'total units sold' : sold
    }

    return data

def get_index_data(soup):
    try:
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_='s-item__link')
    except:
        links = []

    
    urls = [item.get('href') for item in links]
    return urls


def write_csv(data, url):
    with open('output.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        row = [data['title'], data['currency'], data['price'], data['total units sold'], url]

        writer.writerow(row)



def main():    
    url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=mens+shoes&_sacat=0'
    soup = get_data(url)
    
    if not soup is None:
        products = get_index_data(soup)
        #print(products)

        for link in products:
            soup = get_data(link)
            
            if not soup is None:
                data =  get_detail_data(soup)
                write_csv(data, link)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Small heads-up: You should clean up your code / provide a clean sample, try to avoid repeating statements, e.g. the repetitive try/except error handling in your code, you could use a wrapper. Here's an example of how to avoid the error handling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661994/beautifulsoup-return-none-if-html-element-not-found

Comment: sold = soup.find('span', class_='vi-qtyS-hot-red').a.text.strip().split(' ')[0] MIGHT need another strip() at the end. I wouldn't be surprised if you've got a newline in the last column's data, messing you up. However, until you reformat this question as @jpaodev suggested, it's going to be tricky for me to give you an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try first loading the data, then try to clean the data by getting rid of the null values. it is possible that the data could have null values or empty values in few cells then try ```.isnull`` function to see, example: -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lane':['', np.nan]})
print (df)
  lane
0     
1  NaN

bigdata_null_zones = pd.DataFrame({'lane':['AZ','NL','AB', 'BL','AZ']})
print (bigdata_null_zones)
  lane
0   AZ
1   NL
2   AB
3   BL
4   AZ
```

there could be another function `.fillna` where this will fill up all the NA values if there are any.