# BeautifulSoup: Check at text field level if HTML tag match not found

Tags: python

Extracting data from webpage in HTML with tags and classes as follows.

On certain webpages, the phone no. is missing, so the script fails.

Basically, if the phone no. exists (like, `<a href="tel:(111) 222-1111" class="phone-number" data-clickstream-phone-module>(111) 222-1111</a>`), then the following works perfectly - it pulls the phone no. and puts it in the output file.

But if the phone no. is missing (like, `<p class="no-phone-no">No number available</p>`), then this script fails.

```
    with open(filename, "w+") as output:

    #For Factory Name and & phone no.
        for a in soup.select('.head-desc'):
            facdetails = [
                a.select_one('h3').text,
                a.select_one('.phone-number').text,
            ]
            output.write('-'.join(facdetails)+'\n')
```

I want to implement a check at the (`a.select_one('.phone-number').text`) field level, such that if the phone no. in not available, it simply append/write "No number available" to the output file, and proceeds with the further code processing, instead of failing and halting the script.

Any inputs please?

PS: I did go through this SO thread - [BeautifulSoup: Return None if HTML element not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661994/beautifulsoup-return-none-if-html-element-not-found), but it seems to offer solution which works at the entire SOUP element level. I am looking for checking at "a.select_one('.phone-number').text" level due to code requirements.

There are multiple fields like this to process, so I'm looking for a check and handling at field level

Error message that gets generated:

```
---> 22                     a.select_one('.phone-number').text,

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: as you said `But if the phone no. is missing`  text returns a string so if there's no string will return `None`.

Comment: @amd - the issue is that class (class="no-phone-no") itself is different in case of phone no. missing, and in case the no. is available (<a href="tel:(111) 222-1111" class="phone-number" data-clickstream-phone-module>(111) 222-1111</a>) - that's where it is failing. So need a mechanism to handle both.

Answer (score 1):

Try this will solve your problem if the text return `None` the script won't fail, in other words, if there is no phone number in `<p class="no-phone-no">No number available</p>` will pass it and find a field with phone number.

```
try:
    for a in soup.select('.head-desc'):
        facdetails = [
            a.select_one('h3').text,
            a.select_one('.phone-number').text,
        ]
        output.write('-'.join(facdetails)+'\n')
except AttributeError:
    facdetails = [a.select_one('h3').text] # Edit
```

Comment: Thanks - was not aware of the AttributeError part, which worked perfectly.

Comment: Today, encountered another issue with this proposed solution. It DOES NOT work perfectly - if ph no. is missing, it skips printing the h3 text altogether, and hence this fails. My requirement (as stated in the q) is to have a field level check. Even if ph no is missing, it should still print the h3 text. I have come up with alternate solution - i.e. try one field at a time in the try-except block, and that works perfectly. Lengthy code, but still works as needed. Thanks

Comment: Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest things is to add try .. catch. Simple is better :)